# Getting error downloading java programmer

Tags: java

```
E: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.iitb.ac.in/os/ubuntu/archives/pool/main/o/openjdk-7/icedtea-7-jre-jamvm_7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Failed to open file.  '

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I got this error while writing the following commnad:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

I don't have any is idea why, I am very new to ubuntu, please answer in simple language.

Comment: i did sudo apt-get update...it is saying error over there also

Comment: Well could you add the error that you get from `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.iitb.ac.in/os/ubuntu/archives/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Failed to open file.  '

W: Failed to fetch ftp://ftp.iitb.ac.in/os/ubuntu/archives/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to fetch file, server said 'Failed to open file.  '

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: i think its the same error

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Answer (score 1):

Sound like you may need to chage mirrors and resynchronize the package index files from their sources.

open `Ubuntu Software Centre`

And choose `Edit -> Software Services -> Ubuntu Software -> Download From`

Since your current mirror is in India i'm gussing you would like one close to that. Navigate to `India -> mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in` select the protocol as `http`

[image]

Close Software Centre and then open a terminal and try the below command.

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`

Comment: Yeah, my problem got fixed, our server was down..

Comment: @Manish Great You should answer your own question then.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the mirror Manish.

To do this , go to **System Settings** -> **Softwares & Updates** -> **Ubuntu Software** and select '**Main Server**' or '**Other...**' to select other mirrors.

If you select **Other...** option you can select any other mirror other than the Indian mirrors

[image: Ubuntu Softwares & Updates Window]